# 'Trick' a plugin (WP-Members) to think the blog language has changed for a single page

Tags: multi-language, language, translation

I'm trying to avoid installing a full blown multi-language plugin on my site, and I'm *nearly* there.

Just one thing, I need to control whether this plugin – [WP-Members](http://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/) – are getting translated or not on a per page basis.

Default language is Norwegian, and all pages that are children of /en/ are automatically being set to English (using [this method](http://beta.beantin.se/wordpress-setting-language-individual-pages/)). The plugin are using .po/.mo-files, but changing the html-code doesn't make the plugin change its language.

Is it possible to somehow trick the plugin to think the blog is in another language?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of.  Any localized plugin such as WP-Members runs off of the "locale" that WordPress is set to.  This value can be filtered for WP as a whole using the `locale` filter.  But it can also be filtered for plugins using [`plugin_locale`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_locale/)

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_locale/

To use `plugin_locale` specific to the text domain for the plugin* (which in this case is 'wp-members')

```
add_filter( 'plugin_locale', 'my_plugin_locale_filter', 10, 2 );
function my_plugin_locale_filter( $locale, $domain ) {

    // If the text domain is 'wp-members'
    if ( 'wp-members' == $domain ) {
        /*
         * This logic adapted from the method you referenced at
         * http://beta.beantin.se/wordpress-setting-language-individual-pages/
         * Note that the function get_top_parent_page_id() from that example
         * is used here, and the logic is not adapted to your specific 
         * question (i.e. I assume the default $postLanguage value is
         * Norwegian in your case and you are switching it to English) so 
         * change this to match what you are doing with the other elements
         * being used from that process.
         */
        $postLanguage = "en-GB";
        if (is_page()) {
                $svPageID = get_top_parent_page_id(); // ID of parent page
                if ($svPageID == "565") { // ID of the "på svenska" page
                    $postLanguage = "sv";    
                }
            $locale = $postLanguage;
        }
    }

    // Always return the value being filtered.
    return $locale;
}
```

*The text domain for any plugin should be noted in the header of the plugin's main file.  For example, if you open wp-members.php and look at the plugin header, you will find this listed under the heading "Text Domain:".